# What is the best way to center an html element within its containing element?

Tags: html, css, center

Let's say you have the following chunk of code:

```
<div id="container">
  <someelement>This is any element.</someelement>
</div>
```

What's the best CSS I could use to horizontally center "someelement" within its containing div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your `<someelement>` is an inline element (i.e defaults to display: inline) apply text-align: center to its container. If `<someelement>` is a block element set left and right margin to auto and remember to set a width (block elements default to take all available horizontal space unless a width is stated explicitly). 
You may have to use both methods if you want it to work in IE 5.5 and below too.

Answer (score 11):

JaredPar has the right idea, but here's a cleaner way to do what you're looking for ;)

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}

#container someelement {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Why 0 auto vs auto?  Not a CSS buff so the obvious may be the answer

Comment: Jared: 0 auto is cleaner than doing margin-left/margin-right separately.  Functionally they're the same (at least, I'm 99% sure they are).

Comment: 0 is for top and bottom margins and auto for left and right margins

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<someelement style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">This is any element</someelement>
```