# Center a child element (CSS)

Tags: css

if i have markup like

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
  </ul>
<nav>
```

and i want to center the nav (either `<nav>` or `<ul>` or whatever is appropriate is ok with me). FYI: this for horizontal pagination, so `<li>` and `<a>` are floated left

how can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to center an html element within its containing element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395484/what-is-the-best-way-to-center-an-html-element-within-its-containing-element)

Answer (score 2):

See:

[Centre widthless floats](http://www.pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm)

Answer (score 1):

oh i found the answer http://24ways.org/2005/centered-tabs-with-css

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block` instead of floats, but beware IE7.